# How to make my contact form responsive with ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net

So I've been on this for a bit and can't seem to figure out what needs to be done to make this contact form responsive.. I am working on this on Visual Studio and there are way too many files for me to figure out at the moment. I have tried to use the main HTML as "input" and that would've made it a lot easier, except for the fact that I have to work in ASP.NET code.

Any help would be grateful.

```
<div class="contact_form_box hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="float: right;">
            <div id="contact_form">
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                <hr>
                <h2>Send us a message</h2>
                <fieldset>
                    <%--<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" tabindex="1" runat="server" required>--%>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FirstName" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="15px" placeholder="First Name" ></asp:TextBox>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <%--<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" tabindex="2" runat="server" required>--%>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_LastName" runat="server"  ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="15px" placeholder="Last Name"></asp:TextBox>

                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <%--<input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" tabindex="3" runat="server" required>--%>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Email" runat="server"  ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="15px" placeholder="Email Address"></asp:TextBox>

                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <%--<input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" tabindex="4" runat="server" maxlength="12" required>--%>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Phone" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="15px" placeholder="Phone Number"></asp:TextBox>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Message" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="15px" Height="100px" placeholder="Message" ></asp:TextBox>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <center>
                    <asp:Button name="submit" type="submit" id="btn_Submit" runat="server" CssClass="btn_submit" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_AddContacts_Click" />
                        </center>
                </fieldset>
            </div>



.contact_form_box {
            margin-top:0px;
            max-width: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            position: relative;
            float: right;
        }

        #fname, #lname {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #contact_form {
            font-family: open sans;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 30px;
            color: #777;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            background: #F9F9F9;
            padding: 25px;
            margin: 0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #contact_form h1 {
            color: #777;
            display: block;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #contact_form h2 {
            margin: 5px 0 15px;
            display: block;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 400;
            text-align: center;
        }

        fieldset {
            border: medium none !important;
            margin: 0 0 10px;
            min-width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #contact_form input[type="text"],
        #contact_form input[type="email"],
        #contact_form input[type="tel"],
        #contact_form input[type="url"],
        #contact_form textarea {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #cccccc;
            background: #ffffff;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            line-height: 1.2em;
        }

            #contact_form input[type="text"]:hover,
            #contact_form input[type="email"]:hover,
            #contact_form input[type="tel"]:hover,
            #contact_form input[type="url"]:hover,
            #contact_form textarea:hover {
                -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
                transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
                border: 1px solid #aaa;
            }

        #contact_form textarea {
            height: 100px;
            max-width: 100%;
            resize: none;
            line-height: 1.2em;
        }

        #contact_form button[type="submit"] {
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            background: #364e80;
            color: #ffffff;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        #contact_form button[type="submit"]:hover {
            background: #364e80;
            -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }

        #contact_form button[type="submit"]:active {
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

        #contact_form input:focus,
        #contact_form textarea:focus {
            outline: 0;
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
        }
```